# Is there any way to control a switch without using a v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a switch inside a prepend, so when I click the switch an input field slides out.

```
         <b-input-group-prepend is-text>
            <span>{{ 'Click here' }}</span>
            <b-form-checkbox switch v-model="myData" class="ml-2 mr-n2">
            </b-form-checkbox>
          </b-input-group-prepend>
```

I want the switch to always be checked (or "true") when I load the page. To do this I will need to create a v-model called "checked" or something similar and set it to true, but I already have a v-model for the switch which shows some data that I want to display in the input field, so is there any other way of getting the switch to display as checked without a v-model?

Comment: Have you tried to set you're v-model to true in created hook ?

Comment: Fill your 'myData' with the value you want on load or mount

Comment: You need to change your logic. Your v-model need to be a boolean, and initialise him to true. This solve your problem, in second time you want to display some data (information) to your user, so display inside your switch or in a div ```myData```, only if your v-model is true.